# Select list element programmatically using name stored as string

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list

```
myList = list(a = 1, b = 2)
names(myList)
# [1] "a" "b"
```

I want to select element from 'myList' by name stored in as string.

```
for (name in names(myList)){
     print (myList$name)
}
```

This is not working because  name = "a", "b". My selecting line actually saying `myList$"a"` and `myList$"b"`. I also tried:

```
print(myList$get(name))
print(get(paste(myList$, name, sep = "")))
```

but didn't work. Thank you very much if you could tell me how to do it.

Comment: Try `myList[[name]]`. Also, `print` requires parentheses in R, like `print(x)` not `print x`.

Comment: try `myList[[name]]`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `paste(myList$, name, sep = "")` is not valid R syntax. You need to quote all non-variable elements.

Answer (score 9):

`$` does exact and partial match, `myList$name` is equivalent to

```
`$`(myList, name)
```

As @Frank pointed out, the second argument `name` won't be evaluated, but be treated as a literal character string. Try `` ?`$` ``and see the document.

In your example. `myList$name` will try to look for `name` element in `myList`

That is why you need `myList[[name]]`

Comment: I think "for exact match" might not be a full explanation. In fact, `$` supports *partial matching*. The point is that `$` does not evaluate it's second argument (the part that appears on the right hand side). Btw, to escape the backquote, you can use a backslash or nest the code excerpt in some extra `\``s (though I'm not sure how many are needed).

Comment: @Frank Good to know that! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
for (name in names(myList)) {
   print(myList[[name]]) 
}
```