# How to select a part of a word within a list in R

Tags: r, string, list

I have a list, where I have the optimal models ordered by some criteria. I would like to get the name of the variable. For example, for the index [1,1], I get the following:

> ```
> print(opt_dos_variables_2[1,1])
> c...Intercept.....ICI....LC.. 
>                         "ICI"
> ```

```
I just want the string between " ", i.e., the ICI.

What should I modify?

Thanks!
```

Comment: This may help you ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292450/r-select-element-from-list-by-name-string

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub` for a base R option:

```
input <- "c...Intercept.....ICI....LC.. 
                    \"ICI\""
output <- sub("^.*\"(.*?)\".*$", "\\1", input)
output

[1] "ICI"
```

If you wanted to use this logic against an entire list, you could use `lapply` with the above call to `sub` as the inline function, e.g.

```
lapply(your_list, function(x) sub("^.*\"(.*?)\".*$", "\\1", x))
```